# Apachebench making more requests than I ask for

Tags: node.js, benchmarking, apachebench

I am trying to use apachebench to make a number of requests to test my server.  However it often times makes a ton more requests than I ask for.  I am using this to test a node.js server which uses express.

```
ab -n 1 http://myserver/
```

It seems finicky as sometimes it will make only one request, but other it will make 10s to 100s of requests.  The bad part is that it still just reports it made only one request.  Am I doing something wrong?  Does this have anything to do with node.js being asynchronous?

Anyone else had problems using 'ab' to benchmark a node.js server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem with ab on OSX Lion:

http://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2012/07/08/fix-apache-bench-ab-on-os-x-lion

That fixed my problem.